# Erlang httpc:request garbles response with UTF-8 encoded body content

Tags: http, unicode, character-encoding, erlang

I'm having some trouble getting properly encoded UTF-8 content from a website using httpc:request.

I've got the function:

```
fetch(Url) ->
    httpc:request(get, {Url, [{"User-Agent", ?USERAGENT}]}, [{autoredirect, false}], [{body_format, binary}]).
```

And I'm calling it with:

```
fetch("http://chateauvolterra.com").
```

If you look at that site, you'll see that it's got a declared encoding of UTF-8 and some unicode characters like "Château". Unfortunately, when I get the response back, the extended characters are garbled.

I've tried getting the body_format in both string and binary formats, but both have the same issue. I've also tried the ibrowse library, but it seems to have the same issue.

Is there some kind of system-wide encoding setting that could be buggering things up?

How can I get the HTTP body content off the wire without mangling the unicode characters in the document?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the characters actually garbled, or is that just a consequence of how you're looking at them?  Try `file:write_file("myfile", Body)` and check if `myfile` contains the correct bytes.

Comment: To user2843307, Legoscia is right, I made the test he suggests: extract the body `{ok,{_,_,Body}} = fetch("http://chateauvolterra.com").`, write into a file and open it with word specifying UTF-8 and everything is ok. What is weird, is that even when using `io:setopts(standard_io,[{encoding,utf8}]).` and printing using the t format `io:format("~ts~n",[L]).` I got strange (but different) characters in the console.

Comment: Ok, the file:write_file("myfile", Body) suggestion works for me as well. I gather than I'll have to go through the app and make sure that we're always dealing with binary rather than converting to list/string before saving to the database (which is where I eventually see the wonky characters).

Comment: Well, I tracked down where I was changing my HTML from binary to string, and now everything is working! I can see the correctly-displayed unicode characters in SQL after my erlang program runs!
Thanks to legoscia for pointing me in the right direction!